# Spring :Why can't configure two ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer in separated .xml?

Tags: spring

Greetings,

I am working on a spring based web application. Situation is :

1. there are two .xml file one application-context.xml , other is default-context.xml
2. application-context.xml will be load to web context when tomcat started ,which is configured in web.xml
3. application-context.xml ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer loaded some properties.and import **default-context.xml**

   because default-context.xml is in another project, and I want it have its own .properties(default-context.properties) file and set up a ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer for it to load the properties.

the current result is that : the properties in default-context.properties is not loaded, and the ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer in **default-context.xml** is not inited. It reports

> can't resolve placeholder for xxxxxx"

I tried some combinations,

1.to load default-context.properties in application-context.xml 's ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ,its worked.

2.to load default-context.properties in application-context.xml 's **PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer** ,NOT work. I guess its because the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer can't be load to servlet context?

3.loading default-context.properties in default-context.xml in both ways (ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer or PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer)
NOT work.

I can't figure out why **there's only one ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer can be configured in servlet context**?

configuration is like :
in application-context.xml

```
      <class="org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:etc/system.properties
            </value>
```

...

in default-context.xml :

```
 <bean id="tempName123"
    class="org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" >
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
           <value>classpath:etc/default-datasource.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use different placeholder prefix and suffix for second bean. With following declaration you can use placeholder as #[some.property.name].

```
<bean  class="org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
p:location="classpath:etc/default-datasource.properties" 
p:placeholderPrefix="#["
p:placeholderSuffix="]">
    </bean>
```

Comment: for Ritesh, Thanks for your reply. I've tried this approach ,arent work.  The second ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer bean was not init nor loaded by the context.

Comment: @Zac, I tested it in a JUnit class and seems to be working without any other configuration. I found this jira on this subject: https://jira.springframework.org/browse/SPR-6428. Could you try with 'ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders' and 'order' properties on both configurer beans? That might work without declaring placeholder prefix and suffix.